# RTMP server with OpenCV (python)

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, rtmp

I'm trying to process an RTMP stream in Python, using OpenCV2 but I'm not able to get OpenCV to capture it (i.e. act as RTMP server).

I can run FFmpeg/FFplay from the command line and receive the stream successfully.
What could cause OpenCV to fail opening the stream in listening mode?

Here is my code:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtmp://0.0.0.0:8000/live", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open video source")
    exit()
```

And the output:

```
[tcp @ 00000192c490d640] Connection to tcp://0.0.0.0:8000 failed: Error number -138 occurred
[rtmp @ 00000192c490d580] Cannot open connection tcp://0.0.0.0:8000 
Cannot open video source
```

edit2: Output with debug logging turned on:

```
output of the python script with debug logging on:
[DEBUG:0@0.017] global videoio_registry.cpp:218 cv::`anonymous-namespace'::VideoBackendRegistry::VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Builtin backends(9): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); MSMF(970); DSHOW(960); CV_IMAGES(950); CV_MJPEG(940); UEYE(930); OBSENSOR(920)
[DEBUG:0@0.026] global videoio_registry.cpp:242 cv::`anonymous-namespace'::VideoBackendRegistry::VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Available backends(9): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); MSMF(970); DSHOW(960); CV_IMAGES(950); CV_MJPEG(940); UEYE(930); OBSENSOR(920)
[ INFO:0@0.031] global videoio_registry.cpp:244 cv::`anonymous-namespace'::VideoBackendRegistry::VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Enabled backends(9, sorted by priority): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); MSMF(970); DSHOW(960); CV_IMAGES(950); CV_MJPEG(940); UEYE(930); OBSENSOR(920)
[ WARN:0@0.037] global cap.cpp:132 cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(FFMPEG): trying capture filename='rtmp://192.168.254.101:8000/live' ...
[ INFO:0@0.040] global backend_plugin.cpp:383 cv::impl::getPluginCandidates Found 2 plugin(s) for FFMPEG
[ INFO:0@0.043] global plugin_loader.impl.hpp:67 cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\me\src\opencv\.venv\Lib\site-packages\cv2\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg490_64.dll => OK
[ INFO:0@0.047] global backend_plugin.cpp:50 cv::impl::PluginBackend::initCaptureAPI Found entry: 'opencv_videoio_capture_plugin_init_v1'
[ INFO:0@0.049] global backend_plugin.cpp:169 cv::impl::PluginBackend::checkCompatibility Video I/O: initialized 'FFmpeg OpenCV Video I/O Capture plugin': built with OpenCV 4.9 (ABI/API = 1/1), current OpenCV version is '4.9.0' (ABI/API = 1/1)
[ INFO:0@0.055] global backend_plugin.cpp:69 cv::impl::PluginBackend::initCaptureAPI Video I/O: plugin is ready to use 'FFmpeg OpenCV Video I/O Capture plugin'
[ INFO:0@0.058] global backend_plugin.cpp:84 cv::impl::PluginBackend::initWriterAPI Found entry: 'opencv_videoio_writer_plugin_init_v1'
[ INFO:0@0.061] global backend_plugin.cpp:169 cv::impl::PluginBackend::checkCompatibility Video I/O: initialized 'FFmpeg OpenCV Video I/O Writer plugin': built with OpenCV 4.9 (ABI/API = 1/1), current OpenCV version is '4.9.0' (ABI/API = 1/1)
[ INFO:0@0.065] global backend_plugin.cpp:103 cv::impl::PluginBackend::initWriterAPI Video I/O: plugin is ready to use 'FFmpeg OpenCV Video I/O Writer plugin'
[tcp @ 00000266b2f0d0c0] Connection to tcp://192.168.254.101:8000 failed: Error number -138 occurred
[rtmp @ 00000266b2f0cfc0] Cannot open connection tcp://192.168.254.101:8000
[ WARN:0@5.630] global cap.cpp:155 cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(FFMPEG): can't create capture
[DEBUG:0@5.632] global cap.cpp:225 cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO: choosen backend does not work or wrong. Please make sure that your computer support chosen backend and OpenCV built with right flags.
Cannot open video source
[ INFO:1@5.661] global plugin_loader.impl.hpp:74 cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryRelease unload C:\Users\me\src\opencv\.venv\Lib\site-packages\cv2\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg490_64.dll
```

Here is the output of cv2.getBuildInformation()

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.9.0 =====================================
  Version control:               4.9.0

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2023-12-31T11:21:12Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.17763 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.24.2
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015
    CMake build tool:            MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1900
    Configuration:               Debug Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (8 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (36 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.24247.2)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP   /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /INCREMENTAL:NO  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /debug /INCREMENTAL  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          wsock32 comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32
    3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf ade ittnotify libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf zlib ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    java world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI:                           WIN32UI
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.3)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.3-62)
      SIMD Support Request:      YES
      SIMD Support:              NO
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.5.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      YES

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2021.11.0 [2021.11.0]
           at:                   D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2021.11.0)
              at:                D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)
    Flatbuffers:                 builtin/3rdparty (23.5.9)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.7.9/x64/python.exe (ver 3.7.9)
    Libraries:                   C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.7.9/x64/libs/python37.lib (ver 3.7.9)
    numpy:                       C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.17.0)
    install path:                python/cv2/python-3

  Python (for build):            C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.7.9\x64\python.exe

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    Java:                        YES (ver 1.8.0.392)
    JNI:                         C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.392-8/x64/include C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.392-8/x64/include/win32 C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.392-8/x64/include
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.7/cmake-install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

edit: Receiving the stream with ffplay from command line:

```
>ffplay.exe -i "rtmp://0.0.0.0:8000/live"  -listen 1 -f flv
ffplay version 2024-02-04-git-7375a6ca7b-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2003-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --pkg-config=pkgconf --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      58. 36.101 / 58. 36.101
  libavcodec     60. 38.100 / 60. 38.100
  libavformat    60. 20.100 / 60. 20.100
  libavdevice    60.  4.100 / 60.  4.100
  libavfilter     9. 17.100 /  9. 17.100
  libswscale      7.  6.100 /  7.  6.100
  libswresample   4. 13.100 /  4. 13.100
  libpostproc    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
[rtmp @ 0000018a564ed340] Unexpected stream , expecting livef=0/0
    Last message repeated 1 times
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://0.0.0.0:8000/live':KB sq=    0B f=0/0
  Metadata:
    fileSize        : 0
    audiochannels   : 2
    2.1             : false
    3.1             : false
    4.0             : false
    4.1             : false
    5.1             : false
    7.1             : false
    encoder         : obs-output module (libobs version 30.0.2)
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 163 kb/s
  Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2560 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn
   7.54 A-V: -0.024 fd=  18 aq=   24KB vq=  498KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Comment: You have VLC player?

Comment: Did u push the Stream on same server ? Please also include the ffmpeg command and Output in the question

Comment: @Christoph: yes, running the python code and ffplay on the same machine (windows laptop). I get the same error on Linux too.

Comment: @toyotaSupra: VLC does not suit me. My aim is to process the video stream with OpenCV.

Comment: Could u Just test 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0 Just to get sure thats not a weird opencv issue

Comment: @Christoph, I tried with 'localhost', '127.0.0.1' and my interfaces IP address: always same error.

Comment: Show the ffplay command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256865/discussion-between-overnout-and-christoph).

Comment: Use a republisher like https://github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx to push and recv your Stream, because u cant act like an server with opencv as u did it with ffmpeg ..-listen.